# ListView, clicking on one item, all item selected

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview

I try to implement an efficient listViewAdapter in this way:

```
if (itemView == null) {  

  itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
  holder = new ViewHolder();
  ...
  holder.background = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_background);
  ...          
  itemView.setTag(holder);

}else{ 

  holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();

}
```

Items in listView are similar to:

```
public class MyItem {
    ...
    boolean isRed;
    ...
}
```

I have a selector for background like this (this selector is setted in android:background, in the XML R.layout.item), named selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed" />

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_no_pressed" />

</selector>
```

In the listViewAdapter, I have:

```
if (myItems.get(position).getIsRed())
      holder.background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_red);
```

where:

```
ArrayList<myItem> myItems = ...
```

**My problem:**
Logically, in this way, items are shown with background "@drawable/background_no_pressed", and pressing on one item, background in this item changes to "@drawable/background_pressed" (the rest of items in list stay with "no pressed" background). Red background is shown in `myItems(position).getIsRed()==true` , but logically when you scroll the list, other items are shown with red background (because they keep the view holder).

So I have to add to the conditional:

```
if (myItems.get(position).getIsRed()){
      holder.background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_red);
}else{
      holder.background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
}
```

But adding this, the behavior changes, because now, when I click on one item, this item changes its background to "@drawable/background_pressed", **but the rest** (except items with getIsRed() == true) **are shown with "pressed background" too**, as if all of them were pressed (although Log indicates that only the item is pressed, it's only an issue of viewing).

I can fix this, by changing the listViewAdapter removing the conditional if (itemView == null ), and setting a new holder for each item, instead one holder for each view, but I think that this is not efficient.

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Of course because setting the field isRed to true and then passing it to the next view it will be true again, you have to check the field every time getView is called.

Comment: Sorry, I think that I have not explained correctly. I edit my explanation.

Comment: Where do you have put your if(isRed()) in your Adapter??!! In if/else or where??

Comment: I only can recommend debugging `getView()` method, you obviosly have mistaken somewhere. You should also post the full code of `getView()`

Comment: are you able to upload a video? i think i got it but i'm not sure.